# How to merge a dynamically created .xml-file with the main AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm developing an android app and have made a script that can generate a .xml file dynamically based on certain values. The content it generates are a bunch of `<intent-filter>` elements.

After generating the file I want to use android's [AndroidManifest-merging](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge) to merge it into my main AndroidManifest.xml

The various documentation around the web states, that merging is possible by using different build types/flavors/etc or by having the manifest in its own module (because the manifest in dependencies will always be merged into the main manifest).

The issue is that I dont wan't to use different build types/flavors, I want this file to be merged into AndroidManifest.xml across all build-types. So my idea was:

1. create a AndroidManifest.xml file somewhere in the project
2. write content to it
3. make android merge the manifests as if my manifest was placed in one of the build-type-folders.

My questions is whether or not this is actually possible? and if so, where  (in the project-structure) do I put my created manifest.xml file and how do I make android merge them?

File-structure of what I have in mind:

```
- android
| - app
|   - src
|     - main
|       - AndroidManifest.xml (main)
|     - someFolderName
|       - AndroidManifest.xml (my generated one)
```

I guess one solution could be to create a separate module for the project, which only contains the AndroidManifest.xml file that I want to merge, but I'm hoping that my initial idea is possible, as it seems simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was to create a separate module/project within the main project. The new module/project should only be responsible for generating the dynamically created xml and writing it to its own AndroidManifest.xml. This will make the app automatically merge all AndroidManifests from sub-modules with the main AndroidManifest.xml when it builds.